# TFS build custom parameter always null

Tags: c#, wpf, tfs, tfsbuild

I created a custom process parameter and I use dialog to enter values in the guid of queue new build it work fine but when i run a build the value of this parameter always null or if I define default value is always by default.

I read that it because

> Process parameters aren’t restricted to simple types (such as Boolean, string, and integer);
>   they also can be complex types (such as enumerations, arrays, and custom classes) that can
>   be further comprised of simple types and other complex types. Process parameters are
>   stored against the build definition or the build itself by serializing them as XAML, so the only
>   requirement is that your complex type supports this

How can I do this "serializing them as XAML"???

My parameter look like this:

```
public class IMVersion 
{
    public IMVersion()
    {
        version = new Version(SVBuildActivity.FindLatest(SVBuildActivity.IM_RELEASES_PATH));
    }
    public IMVersion(Version v)
    {
        version = v;
    }
    Version version { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return version.ToString();
    }      
}
```

Comment: my visual studio is 2010

Comment: The xaml coment likly refers to option to initialize and provide values in build template workflow. Otherwise the value is stored inside database under BuildDefinition object, process parameters are serialized (presumably xml). I would start by exposing at least one property, not sure what the dialog is doing if you dont have anything to set. The null/default leads to believe that IMVersion(Version v) constructor is used each time with null and default. I would move the retrieval of version into method and call it from template and make version property public and leave only empty constructor.